# Why do I get "arr[i] is undefined" in my JS nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I can't figure out why this is not working. I know the issue comes from the 8th line in the condition `if(arr[i][j]===elem)`.

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {

      if(arr[i][j]===elem) {

        newArr.push(arr.splice(i,1));

      }
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

if I enter in my console a test like :

```
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

I get the error `arr[i] is undefined`.

Comment: You're removing `arr[i]`s from `arr`, which shortens the array. Then at some point in the inner loop `arr[i]` becomes undefined because of all the removals.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are modifying the length of your array inside your loop. You have `arr.splice(i,1)` on the inside of your loop; every time that gets called, your array shortens by `1`. Eventually, your array gets too short, and you attempt to read an item out of bounds. You can prove this by commenting out that line inside the `if` block; your code will run without errors.

I'm not sure exactly what values you're trying to put in `newArr`, but there's no reason to modify `arr` to get your values. Just read the value you want from `arr`, and push it to `newArr`, and you'll have no problems.

---

As an aside, is there any reason you have to use `for` loops vs. using native array methods like [`arr.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: Thank you, you're right it makes total sense. I don't know why I didn't see it sooner. By the way the reason I use for loops is because this is a challenge I'm trying to solve from Freecodecamp where I have to use for loops. Thanks again Ryan.